# How to put splitting by multiple columns inside a function?

Tags: r

Let's assume I want to make a function that splits a data frame by some columns and then uses `lapply(select, ...)` on the output list. I know I can select before splitting, in reality I want to use some custom function, `select` is just for the sake of the example. I figured out how to use a single grouping variable:

```r
f <- function(df, group, ...) {
  split(df, getElement(df, substitute(group))) |>
    lapply(dplyr::select, ...)
}
```

I can invoke `f(iris, Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)` to get a list of sepal lengths and widths by species. Yet I don't know how to make splitting by multiple columns possible. Outside a function I'd use eg. `split(dataframe, list(dataframe$group1, dataframe$group2))` but I can't find a way to put it into a function. I tried to use `with` but with no success. When I try to put a list in the function's argument I end up with the following error:

```r
#> Error in 'unique.default(x, nmax = nmax)': unique() applies only to vectors
```

The question is – how do I make a function out of this:

```r
split(dataframe, list(dataframe$group1, dataframe$group2) |>
  lapply(select, col1, col2, col3)
```

Comment: hmm... maybe take `...` as the `col#` and then `list(...)` together with a `do.call`?

Comment: @Mossa `col#` aren't the problem, `dataframe$group#` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a hint from [@Roger-123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572068/roger-123) I managed to create a function that doesn't need quoting the columns' names. It doesn't look elegant but it works.

```r
f <- function(df, group, ...) {
  group <- vapply(substitute(group), deparse, "vector") # turns vector of colnames into character vector
  if (length(group) > 1) group <- group[2:length(group)] # deletes "c" if more than one colname was provided
  split(df, df[group]) |>
    lapply(dplyr::select, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach to this. There's probably a way to do it with `group` as list, but I found a way to do it with `group` as a character vector, but does require quoting the column names.

This selects the two columns as passes those to split to use as the basis for splitting the dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(df, group, ...) {
  split(df, mtcars[group]) %>%
    lapply(dplyr::select, ...)
}

f(mtcars, group = c("cyl", "carb"), wt, vs)
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought about using the `[` operator. Yet I'd prefer a version that doesn't require quoting. I've managed to create it, I'll post it below.